# Azure/ Microsoft.Automation automationAccounts/schedules interval property example

Tags: azure, automation

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fVar.png)
according to microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/schedules?tabs=json
arm template resource "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/schedules", has got property interval which is an object "interval": {}, . I would like to create a schedule for my automation job but I want a recurring job, however I have got no idea what should be passed to that object, every single tutorial or example in azureautomation repo on github has got this property as an integer.(it was probably recently changed without any documentation) Any idea what kind of key value pair or any specific object should be passed to this property so I can make my schedule recurring? Thanks I tried to pass different values such as "interval": {interval :1}, but there are so many different possible scenarios. Also if you know any other way how I could make my schedule recurring(except manually setting that up in azure), unfortunately if I pass different value than "OneTime" to the property frequency I get an error saying that for recurring jobs interval should be more than 1, but without example I find it really frustrating to find out what should be there. Thanks

EDIT: added screenshot, it is 100% object according to documentation also vs code says it is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the documentation defines it as an object, but I've never seen it set to anything but an integer.  Just set it to to how often you want the job to run in combination with the frequency.

For example for a job that runs every 6 hours:

```json
          "properties": {
            "description": "Run every 6 hours",
            "expiryTime": "9999-12-31T00:00:00Z",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "interval": 6,
            "timeZone": "Europe/London",
            "frequency": "Hour"
          }
```

Unfortunately the ARM templates for Automation are pretty awful with numerous quirks.  Be wary of the start time, which must be at least 5 minutes in the future, which means that it has to be changed every time the template is deployed.

Comment: 'I ve never seen it set to anything but an integer.'  this is true for me it has been always an integer but when I try to pass an integer there it throws error.

Comment: Do you have an example of your template and the error you are receiving?

Comment: Thanks.  The screenshot is just showing the Visual Code plugin showing a warning as it is validating against the schema.  The template should deploy though.  Do you get an error when you deploy the template?

Comment: it works!!! Thank you for your help I would upvoted your answer unfortunately have not got any reputation :( newbie here, sorry the object in the documentation and plugin warning really confused me

Answer (score 0):

As @Marky mentioned in his answer, you have to consider the startTime and that is has to be changed for each deployment. Since this is very inconvenient especially when using IaC and automated deployments I want to provide a workaround.

```
@description('Start time for the daily job schedule. Default is 01:00 CET. For technical reasons this must be a full datetime and at least five minutes after the current time.')
param dailyStartTime string = '${substring(dateTimeAdd(utcNow(), 'P1D'), 0, 11)}01:00:00Z'
```

It takes the current time, adds one day and replaces the timestamp with a fixed value. This works for me as I don't do deployments between 00:00 and 01:00. I don't get why Microsoft tries to reinvent what cron does perfectly for decades...